# Is the Altar of Burnt Offering for cooking or for consuming by fire?

Tags: korban, meat

Were cuts of meat cooked, was the whole animal roasted, or was meat put in the fire as a pleasing aroma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever was placed on the altar was meant to be completely burned. Anything that was eaten would be cooked separately in regular utensils.

Comment: Was there a bbq/stove in the courtyard? Was the animal skinned before being offered? Were pieces of meat taken from the animal for personal consumption?

Comment: Animals were skinned. The last question depends on the type of sacrifice.

Comment: The 'heave' offering would be somewhat exception to this, would it not? - e.g. Exd. 29:22;25;27-28, Lev. 8

Comment: What is a "heave" offering? I haven't seen that term before.